# Ubuntu 20.04 shift right not functioning

Tags: 20.04

When I installed 20.04, by accident I changed the function of the right shift key when asked. Now it isn't working as a shift key any more. How can I recover this error?
Thanks Hubert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Tweaks (`gnome-tweaks`). On the "Keyboard & Mouse" tab, check "Additional Layout Options". Under, "Switching to another layout", one can assign, among many others, the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. In the absence of more specific information, this could have been set in your case. If that is the case, uncheck the mark left of "Right shift" to return that key to normal use.